# Trigger HTMX call on select2 change event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2, htmx

I have two select fields in my form. The first is a select2, the second is a regular HTML one.

I want to replace the second one with HTMX when I select something in the first. In addition, I need to know what was selected in the first one.

And, because I'm using HTMX I want to avoid loads of ugly JS/jQuery

I know that I can listen to the event [select2.select](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events) but my HTMX never triggers.

```html
<select id="second-select" hx-get="/my-url" hx-trigger="select2.select from:body">...</select>
```

I also tried  `hx-trigger="select2.select from:#select1"`.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong and how I can pass the selected value from the first select?

Thx!
Ronny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select2 is a jQuery library, therefore [it uses the jQuery event system](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#listening-for-events), not the vanilla JS events, so HTMX cannot catch them by itself. You need to create an event bridge between Select2 and HTMX. In the following example we translate the `select2.select` jQuery event to a vanilla JS event and dispatch it to the second select element triggering the HTMX request.

```
<select id="second-select" hx-get="/my-url" hx-trigger="select2.select">...</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Init Select2 on #first-select element
  $('#first-select').select2();

  // Attach to 'select2:select' jQuery event from Select2
  $('#first-select').on('select2:select', (e) => {
    // Dispatch 'select2:select' vanilla JS event to trigger HTMX
    let event = new Event('select2:select');
    document.querySelector('#second-select').dispatchEvent(event);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Oh crazy, never knew that these two event systems are not the same! Explains a lot now 