# How to use hx-trigger with bootstrap selectpicker

Tags: htmx, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm trying to trigger an htmx request off of a bootstrap selectpicker `hidden.bs.select` (https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/#events).

`change` does not work because the selectpicker triggers a change as soon as you select an option and I want to only trigger the event when the select menu is closed.

I've tried both `hx-trigger = "hidden.bs.select"` and `hx-trigger="hidden.bs.select:from document"`. Neither work.

I've gotten around it by doing this, but I'm wondering why the above doesn't just work.

```js
 $('.selectpicker').on(
        'hidden.bs.select',
        function (e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) {
            e.target.dispatchEvent(new Event('selectpickerHidden'));
        }
    );
```

and then in the html doing `hx-trigger="selectpickerHidden"`

Comment: Just saw this and assume it's the same which is annoying :(.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75411134/trigger-htmx-call-on-select2-change-event?rq=2